# Release a lightweight maven POM

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module project that I'd like to consolidate when I release. More specifically, I'd like to have my release POM be a separate lighter version of the POM I use for builds.

Is it possible to have or create a separate POM for releases?

Comment: umm, yes? That's a pretty vague question. Examples please?

Comment: Re-wored the question a bit. Simplest example without bothering with XML - consider a module that has its parent section removed for release.

Comment: If you use @<user> when you add comments, it will notify them that you're trying to get their attention. e.g. @Ryan: ...

Comment: @Josh: What is the intention to use a different pom instead of the one you used for building? This means in other words you are trying to kidding people because you don't use the pom you have used to build your project? So what is the intention/idea/Problem behind that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from putting two poms in a project. If you were to add a second one called pom-release.xml, then you could invoke that pom using

```
mvn -f pom-release.xml <phases and goals>
```